# Get class PropertyInfo by its type

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider that I have the fallowing class

```
export class myClass{
  test?:number;
  test2?:string;
  test3:boolean;
  constructor(){
   this.test3=true;
}
}
```

I want to get a list of the properties and its type that are contained in the class

I want somthing like `.GetProperties<myClass>()` to return `[{name:"test", "type":"number"},etc]`

Is it possible in typescript?

Comment: you can write a getter function

Comment: Its that what I am asking to how? If I know I would not be asking.

Comment: Types are erased at runtime, so I guess it's not possible.

Comment: I can make such literal type: [{name:"test", "type":"number"}]. But like @Nishant said, you can't use it as an value

Comment: Well that what I though too, but just wanted to be sure.